# Thin, won't start as service on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian, environment, thin

Hello I've got problem with start thin as service, my command to run thin is:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/thin start --all /etc/thin
```

it's run server, I've tried to autostart as service, but I run as service:

```
service thin start
```

I got an error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:313:in `to_specs': Could not find 'thin' (>= 0) among 14 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:322:in `to_spec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:58:in `gem'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/thin:22:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

If I run like this:

```
/etc/init.d/thin start
```

Server is started. How I can fix that?

Comment: here: "GEM_PATH=/.gem/ruby/2.1.0", if you run gem env don't you get back GEM PATHS: /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0? couldn't it be that for some reason /root is missing when you run "service thin start"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the thin gem in the project's gemfile. Add it by adding "gem thin" on a new line, then run bundle install to make sure that everything is happy (probably not needed, but still a good idea)